# Linear Interpolation for Smooth Transition - GDScript

Tags: interpolation, godot, linear-interpolation, gdscript

I am trying to have a system that works its way around a 2D grid (a BlendSpace2D for animation) in a smooth fashion.
x values can range from -1 to 1 and same for y values.

I use the following code on a Vector2 to attempt to do this and it fails to do what I wish.

transition is a Vector2 and so is movement_state. movement_state is the Vector2 that determines the end destination of the interpolation based on inputs by the player.

```
transition = transition.linear_interpolate(movement_state, transition_speed * delta)
animation_tree.set("parameters/movement_state/blend_position", transition)
```

It is seemingly scaled down to the value of the second argument, transition_speed * delta, so I do not get the full animation at any point. I also do not get a smooth transition to this scaled point. Any ideas on what I could change to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out. I needed to initialize the transition Vector2 in the _ready() func so it knew where to start. Feel like an absolute idiot after missing that I didnt initialize. Anyways for anyone that is also having issues, I went into more detail while helping another fellow out on the [Godot forums](https://godotforums.org/discussion/comment/39389#Comment_39389) P.S. it is hyperlinked to the comment.